# RecyclerView Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Не могу понять в чём проблема. RecyclerView Запускается, но ничего не показывает:с

```
class AdapterNote(var items:ArrayList<Note>/*,val callback: MyViewHolder.CallBack*/): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNote.MyViewHolder>(){

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int)=MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.item_note, p0, false))

override fun getItemCount():Int=items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MyViewHolder, p1: Int) {
     p0 . bind (items[p1])
}
inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val name = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noteName)
        val description = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noteDescription)
        val date = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noteDate)

    fun bind(item: Note){
        name.text=item.name+""
        description.text=item.text+""
        date.text=item.date+""
    }

}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/noteName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="@dimen/nameSize"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginName"
/>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/noteDescription"
/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="27.02.1998"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginName"
            android:id="@+id/noteDate"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
data class Note(/*val id: Int,*/
val name:String,
val text: String,
val date: String) {
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл проблему. Неправильная инициализиуая RecyclerView в MainActivity/

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var rv=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv)

    rv.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)

    val items= ArrayList<Note>()
    for ( i in 1..1000){items.add(Note("Name", "Decriptions", "27.02.1998")) }

    val myAdapter= AdapterNote(items)
    rv.adapter=myAdapter
}
```

}